# How to make Webstorm "Reformatting Source Code" to change double quotes to single quotes?

Tags: javascript, ide, webstorm

When I push `cmd + alt + l` Webstorm doing some reformating to beautify my JavaScript sources. Ho to make Webstorm automatically change double quotes to single quotes in my sources?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

In Webstorm 2017.1, do the following:

1. Go to File -> Settings | Preferences
2. Choose Editor -> Code Style -> TypeScript
3. Select 'Punctuation' tab
4. Change: `Use 'double' quotes` to `Use 'single' quotes`. (Additionally, you can change `'in new code'` to `'always'`)

[image: Webstorm auto-import change to use double quotes instead of single quotes]

Comment: I found the menu under Webstorm->Preferences in version 2017.3.2

Comment: Same settings available in `WebStrom 2020.3.1`

Answer (score 38):

there is no way to change this on auto-formatting in WebStorm 11; you can only use intentions here (hit `Alt+Enter` on quoted string, choose 'Replace double-quoted string with single-quoted string'.
Note that in WebStorm 12 -2016.x  it's possible to control the auto-generated quotes style (used for auto-imports, etc.) - `Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Other`, `Generated code/Quote marks`.

Since 2017.1.*, it is `Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Punctuation`, `Use <quote style> quotes in <new code/always>`

Comment: In WebStorm `2017.1.4` it is under Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Punctuation, Use {single} quotes in {new code}

Answer (score 12):

This looks to be fixed with the 2016.2 release - there's now an option in the *Editor --> Code Style* settings where you can choose single/double quotes.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/07/webstorm-2016-2-drag-files-into-html-and-quotes-style/

Comment: The force reformatting only works for HTML, but you can select quote style for generated JavaScript.

Comment: I think this has been addressed in the 2016.3 release

Comment: It's very clear in 2017.1 - see https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/#v2017-1-new-code-style-options

Answer (score 4):

Please see the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42909782/2000468.

this answer is for an older version。

see the picture that let you set it quickly.

[image: webstorm 2016.3.3]